# How to add mathjax plugin to ckeditor

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have added mathjax plugin in plugins folder in ckeditor. But, after specifying this particular lines to existed script even the editor also not displaying.Can you please help me out from this problem?
    Before adding mathjax plugin output is like this.[enter image description here][1]
    After adding mathjax plugin output is like this[enter image description here][2]

```
<textarea id="editor1" name="editor1" maxlength="50"></textarea>
     <script type="text/javascript">
                    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
                    extraPlugins: 'mathjax',
                    mathJaxLib: 'http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/2.6-latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML'
                } );
      </script>

      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgDfU.png
      [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJoqH.png
```

Comment: why do you add this line `mathJaxLib`? where did you find such option?

Comment: I have seen this in http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/mathjax.html

Comment: orelse may i know how can i write mathematical expressions in ckeditor?

Comment: what's the error in console?

Comment: I have updated my output as images can you please, check it out?

Comment: yeah, but I need to see errors in console

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 1):

You need also download and install the plugin.
https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/mathjax

Downloade it -> unzip into ckeditor/plugins/ and it will work.

Also remember that multiple plugins must comma separated like this:
extraPlugins = 'mathjax, plugin1, plugin2, etc' , otherwise it will not work too.